spring boot external application.properties create on start
kotlin
can I somehow create if not exist external file application.properties on start of a jar with default property's from inner default file
I was given a task to learn how to configure spring boot applications as a jar
Options I came across are creating sub endpoint for the configuration of already active project and external application.properties filebought options seem good but lack benefits of each other. For example, endpoint configuration cannot configure ports and for application.properties to change smf I have to restart application
For my application build project should be in one jar file and any external files, like application.properties should be generated by jar file.
Can I somehow, at the start of an application, check if the file application.properties exists in the current directory and, if not, create it with parameters from the internal application.properties

Just create the file. Don't copy the internal state there is no need for that.

There are many ways to achieve this.  Here is one approach:

Create a file /src/main/resource/application.properties. Define in this file your default properties, e.g. your endpoint point configurations, ports, and other settings
Create a file outside your application, visible to the runtime jar - say in the same folder that you start the jar file from, call it override.properties
Configure Spring to start looking in its default location then a custom location of something like this: java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,./override.properties

Spring will load the default properties file (1) first and then (2).  If any properties are defined in (2) then these will take precedence over those in (1).
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html#features.external-config.files
